# Connecting two routers with device accessibility behind home cable modem

Tags: router, modem, switch, cable

I have three routers; [the wireless modem gateway, a Linksys device which is in only switch mode and another Linksys router which is in bridge mode]

I have this setup:

```
[cable modem] -> switch -> Router 1 [switch mode] -> Router 2 [bridge mode] -> [devices - xbox, tv, etc]
```

What I want is to be able to use the Router 2 as a wireless access point, and still be able to access the resources connected directly to Router 1. Right now this isnt the case.

They are all on the same subnet, and are using the IP scheme 10.0.0.x

What configuration do I need to use in order to make this work successfully?